# ListPlot3D label is covered by surface in combined graphic

Tags: graphics3d

I'm trying to plot some points on the upper sheet of the hyperboloid.  When I try to label them the label is partially covered by the surface. You can see this in the following code

```
Show[{
  ParametricPlot3D[{Sinh[x] Sin[y], Sinh[x] Cos[y], Cosh[x]}, {x, 0, 
    1}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[1], Yellow}, Mesh -> {5, 10}, 
   PlotPoints -> {2, 100}], 
  ListPointPlot3D[{{Sinh[0.5] Sin[Pi/2], Sinh[0.5] Cos[Pi/2], 
      Cosh[0.5]} -> Style["CS", 15]}]}]
```

[image: Label is blocked by surface]

How can I make the label appear in front of the surface?  I have tried changing Style["CS", 15] to Text["C",{Sinh[0.5] Sin[Pi/2], Sinh[0.5] Cos[Pi/2],Cosh[0.5]}] and it doesn't help.

Thanks!

**Edit**:  I'm using these commands inside a manipulate command (where the size of the hyperboloid changes along with other planes and curves being drawn). and I don't know the final position so moving the text or changing the point of view is not a great solution. I want to look at it from multiple points of view and always be able to see the label. Is there a way to make the labels be rendered last (i.e. on top)?

Answer (score 2):

If you add the label using `Text`, you can change its position to be slightly above the surface:

```
Show[{
  ParametricPlot3D[{Sinh[x] Sin[y], Sinh[x] Cos[y], Cosh[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[1], Yellow}, Mesh -> {5, 10}, PlotPoints -> {2, 100}], 
  ListPointPlot3D[{{Sinh[0.5] Sin[Pi/2], Sinh[0.5] Cos[Pi/2], Cosh[0.5]}}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]],
  Graphics3D[Text["C", {Sinh[0.5] Sin[Pi/2], Sinh[0.5] Cos[Pi/2], Cosh[0.5] + .2}]]
  }]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could change the `ViewPoint`.

```
Show[{ParametricPlot3D[{Sinh[x] Sin[y], Sinh[x] Cos[y], Cosh[x]}, {x, 
    0, 1}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[1], Yellow}, 
   Mesh -> {5, 10}, PlotPoints -> {2, 100}, 
   ViewPoint -> {Pi/3, Pi/3, Pi/3}], 
  ListPointPlot3D[{{Sinh[0.5] Sin[Pi/2], Sinh[0.5] Cos[Pi/2], 
      Cosh[0.5]} -> Style["CS", 15]}]}]
```

[image]